# Restricting access to directories for git server?

Tags: linux, git, admin, raspbian

I'm using my raspberrypi as a Git server. Until I've been using it by myself. Now I would like to give access to a friend. The problem is that the git user also can see everything else on the server. So if he has the ssh-keys to push to the server, he can also SSH in the server and do whatever he wants (well, not everything, he won't have the sudo password).

But still... What's the most secure way to deal with something like this?

I don't want any client to run any commands from this user (if possible) and I want to restrict access to a directory where I mount my external HDD.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a software like [gitolite](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) which handles the access permissions. (Check the software packages for your Raspberry Pi. You will probably find a `gitolite` package.)

Follow the setup instructions. Instead of modifying `.ssh/authorized_keys2` yourself, the software will do this for you. This makes sure the users cannot do anything else than accessing the Git repositories.

Another alternative is [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/install/).